# How to use jQuery or HTML5 to duplicate header and footer on all pages?

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, footer, dry

I know with rails and django you can use templates to write a header and footer once as a separate file, and include it in all of your webpages. I was wondering, can something like this can be achieved with just jQuery or html5? if so, how?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <navigation> include code from header.html here </navigation>
        ...
        some page specific content
        ...
        <footer>include code from footer.html here</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ya, if you use jQuery's `.load()` function. I think it would look something like

`$('footer').load('/assets/myfooter.html');`

and that should do it.

[Documentation available here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

The only thing you can't do is get html from another domain because of the 'same origin policy', which I believe is to prevent CSRF attacks and/or session hijacking.